# xamarin form: flex layout how do fit the contents which larger than container

Tags: listview, xamarin, layout

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="Start">

                    <circle:CircleImage
                        BackgroundColor="Blue"
                        Style="{StaticResource profileStyle}"
                        Source="{Binding TeacherSource}">
                    </circle:CircleImage>

                    <FlexLayout 

                        FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                        Direction="Column" 
                        BackgroundColor="Red" 
                        JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">

                        <Label Text="{Binding TeacherName}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TeacherEmail}"   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TeacherMobile}"  Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TeacherHome}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TeacherWork}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>

                    </FlexLayout>

                </FlexLayout>
```

The above xaml was created inside the datatemplate used in listview. I can have the content showing but the last label was not expanding the flexlayout to fit all content with it.

image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and didn't find a solution to let `flexlayout` expand automatically.  I tried [ForceUpdateSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.cell.forceupdatesize?view=xamarin-forms) but no luck.

If there is only one `FlexLayout`, it will work:

```
<FlexLayout 
             FlexLayout.Grow="1"
             Direction="Column" 
             BackgroundColor="Red" 
             JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">

             <Label Text="{Binding TeacherName}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
             <Label Text="{Binding TeacherEmail}"   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
             <Label Text="{Binding TeacherMobile}"  Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
             <Label Text="{Binding TeacherHome}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>
             <Label Text="{Binding TeacherWork}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"></Label>    
    </FlexLayout>
```

And I find a **Workaroud**:

Change your `flexLayout` to `StackLayout` then it will work:

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="Start">

          <Image Source="Images"></Image>

           <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Image}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Image}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Image}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Image}"></Label>        
           </StackLayout>

 </FlexLayout>
```

Remember set your `listView` **HasUnevenRows="True"** and don't set `rowheight`.

[image]

Comment: Changing to StackLayout worked very good. Thank you